# Type extraction in Scala

Tags: scala, types, covariance

I am pretty new to Scala and advanced programming languages. I try to solve the following problem.

I have got:

```
val s: Seq[SomeMutableType[_]]
```

I assume that all elements in the sequence are of the same type (but do not know which one at this point).

How may I call :

```
def proc[T](v0: SomeMutableType[T], v1: SomeMutableType[T]) { /* ... */ }
```

with something like

```
proc(s(0), s(1))
```

The compiler complains :

> - type mismatch; found : SomeMutableType[_$351] where type _$351 required: 
>     SomeMutableType[Any] Note: _$351 <: Any, but class SomeMutableType is invariant in type T. You 
>     may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)

I thought about that covariant thing, but I do not believe it makes sense in my case. I just want the compiler believe me when I say that s(0) and s(1) are of the same type! I usually do this via some casting, but I cannot cast to SomeMutableType[T] here since T is unknown due to erasure. Of course, I cannot change the definition of proc.

Comment: How do you obtain `s`? Ideally, you should bind your `_` to some type parameter declared in a method or class…

Comment: Actually, it is quite complicated. SomeMutableType is parameterized because it make sens to parameterize it. However, s is an attribute of a class C that usually does not care about the parameter, except in my particular use case (where all elements should be of the same type). I can assume that in my instance of C, all elements of s are of the same type, but it is not true in the general case. Maybe I should use some subclass of C at this point, but it would make some other code quite complicated (introduce factory methods and so on), since classes are generated by a parser.

Comment: "I didn't keep track of the type, but I know it's X." - then cast it to X and manifest your assumption in code. If you don't want to cast then you HAVE TO keep track of the type. It's that simple!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you truly cannot make such a guarantee. For example:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

scala> val s: Seq[Buffer[_]] = Seq(Buffer(1), Buffer("a"))
s: Seq[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_]] = List(ArrayBuffer(1), ArrayBuffer(a))
```

See? You *don't* know that `s(0)` and `s(1)` are of the same type, because they may not be of the same type.

At this point, you should ask a question about what you want to accomplish, instead of asking how to solve a problem in *how* you want to accomplish it. They way you took won't work. Step back, think what problem you were trying to solve with this approach, and ask how to solve that problem.

For instance, you say:

> I assume that all elements in the sequence are of the same type (but do not know which 
>   one at this point).

It may be that what you want to do is parameterize a class or method, and use its type parameter when declaring `s`. Or, maybe, not have an `s` at all.

Comment: I know that I do not "know" that s(0) and s(1) are of the same type, but I would be happy to have some `ClassCastException` or some equivalent if it would not be the case when I call `proc`. The type parameter of my `SomeMutableType` is useful in some parts of my application, but I do not really care about it here.

Comment: What I actually am trying to do here is to model an hypergraph: `SomeMutableType` are nodes that encapsulate a set of typed values. `s` is a sequence of nodes linked by the hyperedge. According to some properties (that can hardly be computed when the hyperedge is created), I can merge all nodes of one given hyperedge in one chosen node and discard the hyperedge. The values of that single node are reduced to the intersection of the sets encapsulated by all nodes. The method that computes the intersection assumes that all values are of the same type, hence my problem…

Comment: @scand1sk Why don't you cast it to `Seq[SomeMutableType[AnyRef]]`, then? Or, if you know the type at the time you are making this call, use `collect` to generate a known-type collection?

Comment: OK, here is where my poor knowledge of Scala strikes. I do not really know the actual difference between [_], [Any] and [AnyRef]. Have you some info about this please?

Comment: @scand1sk Well, `[_]` will _sometimes_ mean `[Any]`, but you should really never use it with that meaning. Instead, stay on the safe side and always say `[Any]` if that's what you mean. The other meaning of `[_]`, which is the case here, is an existential type. `Seq[Buffer[_]]` is a shortcut for `Seq[Buffer[t]] forSome { type t }`. That means `Buffer`'s type parameter is an unspecified type t. `Any` is the supertype of all types, including "primitives". `AnyRef` is like Java's `Object`.

Comment: @scand1sk Here I used `AnyRef` because I know that type erasure turns everything into `AnyRef` at run time -- and even primitives will get boxed. So, whatever else, `Buffer` will contain `AnyRef`.

Comment: @scand1sk Note that any use of `asInstanceOf` is a change to introduce bugs. For instance, the function being called could store an object of a different type, which might cause an exception elsewhere.

Comment: @scand1sk For more information on the types, look existential types as well as `Any`, `AnyRef`, `Null` and `Nothing`, or Scala type hierarchy.

Comment: For future readers, Daniel made a typo. `A[B[_]]` is actually shorthand for `A[B[C] forSome { type C; }]`, not `A[B[C]] forSome { type C; }`.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Scala, but as far as I can see your problem is the use of a wildcard type parameter when you declare s:

```
val s: Seq[SomeMutableType[_]]
```

As far as I understand, type erasure will always happen and what you really want here is a parameterised type bound to where s is initialised.

For example:

```
scala> class Erased(val s: List[_])
defined class Erased

scala> new Erased(List(1,2,3)).s.head
res21: Any = 1
```

If instead you use

```
scala> class Kept[T](val s: List[T])
defined class Kept

scala> new Kept(List(1,2,3)).s.head
res22: Int = 1
```

Then the contents of s retain their type information as it is bound to T. i.e. This is exactly how you tell the compiler "that s(0) and s(1) are of the same type".